# Protected super interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

How can I make an `interface` that solely acts as a super interface for other interfaces (much like an abstract class) protected so that only the interfaces that I create within the same package can extend it, and so that no classes can implement it?

Thank you.

Comment: A top-level class that's declared without `public` is visible only to other classes in the same package, and I think the same is true of `interfaces`.  However, I don't believe there's a way to declare an `interface` that cannot be implemented.

Comment: @ajb Of course, making the interface package-private also prevents its *use* outside the package, not just the ability to implement it, so that may defeat the purpose.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) maybe?

Comment: Thanks @ajb, didn't realize that would make it package protected. Works perfectly now, thanks again

Comment: @Andreas My interpretation was that he was going to define `public` subinterfaces in the package that could then be used outside the package.

Comment: ^I wanted a super interface that just contained a few methods that extending interfaces would then inherit, and I didn't want any use of the super interface outside of the package with these interfaces. Removing the public modifier seems to have accomplished this.

Answer (score 2):

While this is a very old question, it looks like a Java 15 and Java 16 preview feature, ***Sealed Interfaces***, might provide something close to the functionality you are seeking. See the section titled "*Defining Sealed Interfaces*" in [this Oracle documentation on *"Sealed  Classes"*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html):

> *...to seal an interface, add the sealed modifier to its declaration.
> Then, after any extends clause, add the permits clause, which
> specifies the classes that can implement the sealed interface and the
> interfaces that can extend the sealed interface.*

This approach offers a more granular alternative to your proposal of having something akin to a `protected` interface. Use the new `sealed` keyword for the extensible interface, and the new `permits` keyword to explicitly name the interfaces which are allowed to extend the interface. Those interfaces must be within the same package or module as the `sealed` interface.

The new syntax is intuitive and straightforward. Here's Oracle's sample code, which runs fine [with preview enabled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html) in Eclipse 2021-03:

```
public class TestExpressions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // (6 + 7) * -8
        System.out.println(
                new TimesExpr(new PlusExpr(new ConstantExpr(6), new ConstantExpr(7)), new NegExpr(new ConstantExpr(8)))
                        .eval());
    }
}

sealed interface Expr permits ConstantExpr,PlusExpr,TimesExpr,NegExpr {
    public int eval();
}

final class ConstantExpr implements Expr {
    int i;

    ConstantExpr(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int eval() {
        return i;
    }
}

final class PlusExpr implements Expr {
    Expr a, b;

    PlusExpr(Expr a, Expr b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int eval() {
        return a.eval() + b.eval();
    }
}

final class TimesExpr implements Expr {
    Expr a, b;

    TimesExpr(Expr a, Expr b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int eval() {
        return a.eval() * b.eval();
    }
}

final class NegExpr implements Expr {
    Expr e;

    NegExpr(Expr e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public int eval() {
        return -e.eval();
    }
}
```

Note that **Sealed Interfaces** is currently only a Preview Feature, and is therefore subject to modification or removal in future JDK releases.